# I need some explanation for some of this code

Tags: javascript

This a count down timer. I don't understand how `var timer` works. What is its set value after each interval? How does the timer produce the number of minutes and seconds? Could some one break down step-by-step how this bit of code operates?

```
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
```

Comment: What do you need to know specifically? Cause all it does, is repeat at each second -> get the minutes left from the timer, get the seconds left from the timer, add a 0 in case the value is less than 10, display the value in the selected html element, and reduce the timer with 1

Comment: @Icepickle why timer is declared like var timer = duration, seconds, minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
```

Minutes are number of current total seconds divided by 60 (seconds in a minute).

E.g.: 65 / 60 = 1 minute. We just keep the integer part.

```
seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
```

Seconds are calculated as the module 60 of the current total seconds counter.

E.g.: 65 % 60 = 5 (1 minute, 5 seconds)

[Notice that in the second line the parseInt is unnecessary.]

```
var timer = duration, seconds, minutes;
```

this can also be written as:

```
var timer = duration;
var seconds;
var minutes;
```

Comment: thank but my question was more regarding the way var timer is declered why is it like var timer = duration, minutes, seconds ?

Answer (score 1):

You can declare and instialise multiple variables at a time in javascript.

```
var a, 
    b,
    c;
```

is same as

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
```

also you can intialize variable too so

```
var timer = duration, seconds, minutes;
```

is same as writing

```
var timer = duration;
var seconds;
var minutes;
```

(as @Lorenzo already mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

`var timer = duration, seconds, minutes` declares 3 variables with only the first getting initialized. It is the same as writing:

```
var timer = duration;
var seconds;
var minutes;
```